# Reversing X and Y axes on plotted GAM in base R

Tags: r, gam

I would like to plot the output from a GAM with the X and Y axes reversed, such that an output like this:

[image: orig_gam]

is output like this:

[image: flipped_gam]

Is there a good way to do this in base R?

There seems to be some background calculations when plot(GAM) is called, so I can't just simply reverse the order of the input.

Answer (score 3):

The function `plot.gam` invisibly returns a `list` containing enough data to recreate the plot, so you can build a flipped version yourself with this function:

```r
plot_flipped <- function(model) {
  dat <- plot(model)[[1]]
  plot(c(dat$fit), dat$x, ylim = rev(dat$xlim), type = "l", xaxt = "n", 
       xlab = "", ylab = dat$xlab)
  axis(3)
  suppressWarnings(rug(dat$raw, side = 2))
  lines(dat$fit - dat$se, dat$x, lty = 2)
  lines(dat$fit + dat$se, dat$x, lty = 2)
  mtext(dat$ylab, side = 3, padj = -4)
}
```

So, suppose we have a model like this:

```r
mod <- mgcv::gam(mpg ~ s(wt), data = mtcars)
```

The standard plot would be like this:

```
plot(mod)
```

[image]

But our flipped version would be:

```r
plot_flipped(mod)
```

[image]

There are alternative ways that would be easier using extension packages, and you could get a prettier version of the same thing using `ggplot`, but this is probably the simplest way to do it using only base R (without saving the image as a bitmap and rotating it)

<sup>Created on 2023-06-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>